# Unable to create Model tables on Magento2

Tags: magento2, module, model, view

I'm having a hard time making Magento2 create my model tables. This is my code so far:

**app\code\Werules\Chatbot\Model\IncomingMessages.php**

```
<?php

namespace Werules\Chatbot\Model;

use Magento\Cron\Exception;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class IncomingMessages extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime
     */
    protected $_dateTime;

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\Werules\Chatbot\Model\ResourceModel\IncomingMessages::class);
    }

}
```

**app\code\Werules\Chatbot\Model\ResourceModel\Collection.php**

```
<?php

namespace Werules\Chatbot\Model\ResourceModel\Contact;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

/**
 * Contact Resource Model Collection
 *
 * @author      Pierre FAY
 */
class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource collection
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Werules\Chatbot\Model\IncomingMessages', 'Werules\Chatbot\Model\ResourceModel\IncomingMessages');
    }
}
```

**app\code\Werules\Chatbot\Model\ResourceModel\IncomingMessages.php**

```
<?php

namespace Werules\Chatbot\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class IncomingMessages extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('chatbot_incoming_messages', 'id');
    }
}
```

**app\code\Werules\Chatbot\Setup\InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php

namespace Werules\Chatbot\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @throws \Zend_Db_Exception
     */

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        /**
         * Create table 'chatbot_incoming_messages'
         */

        if (!$setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($setup->getTable('chatbot_incoming_messages'))) {
            $table = $setup->getConnection()
                ->newTable($setup->getTable('chatbot_incoming_messages'))
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                    'Message ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'message_content',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    500,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Content'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'is_processed',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN,
                    1,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
                    'Status'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'created_at',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    null,
                    [],
                    'Created at'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'updated_at',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    null,
                    [],
                    'Updated at'
                )
                ->setComment('Incoming Messages Table')
                ->setOption('type', 'InnoDB')
                ->setOption('charset', 'utf8');

            $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**app\code\Werules\Chatbot\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Werules_Chatbot" setup_version="1.0.1" schema_version="1.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

What am I doing wrong? Full code can be found here: https://github.com/blopa/Magento-Chatbot/pull/82/files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried running your InstallSchema.php and it works fine.

I checked my Database and the table was created. If your table is not created maybe because you have run this CLI: `(php bin/magento setup:upgrade)` before.

I suggest you go to your db and please open the table `‘setup_module’`, find and remove a row has module equals to `‘Werules_Chatbot’`. After this, run the command again to install the table.

Here's a link to the reference I got `https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html`

Comment: That was exactly what was happening. Thank you very much :)